# Datablocksize and Freespacepercent for Spools

Tags: teradata, spool

Does the properties of Table like Datablocksize and Freespacepercent is applicable to Spool?
in that case if we have a Table A with Datablocksize x1 and Freespacepercent x2 and Table B with Datablocksize y1 and Freespacepercent y2
what would be the Datablocksize and Freespacepercent of the resulting spool created by joining the two tables?

Note: The Freespace percent property for Spool doesn't make sense though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DatablockSize and FreespacePercent are table only options.

As you said Freespace would be totally useless for a spool, because it's temporary.

And spools always have a maximum blocksize of 255 sectors = 127.5 KB (1 MB in TD14.10).

Comment: Dnoeth the block size for pre 14.10 is 127.5 Kb right?